# count the total number of comments the user has received for his published posts

Tags: posts, users, comments, publish

### I want to count the total number of comments the user has received for his published posts.
for example show:

total comments of your all posts : 47

---

Is there a way to do this?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`get_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) function like so:

```php
$total = get_comments( array(
    'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'type'        => 'comment',
    'count'       => true,
) );

echo 'total comments of your all posts : ' . $total;
```

Just customize the [arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/#parameters) based on your requirements/preferences, and in the above example, I'm retrieving the total number of comments for published posts where the author is the currently logged-in user, but only for comments of the `comment` type.

And if you want, you can use the `status` argument to limit to certain status only, e.g. `approve` to count approved comments only.

Comment: I used this code but got an error
A major error has occurred on this website.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot a `,` after the `'publish'`. So please try again?

Comment: I meant, I have revised the code (but I simply added the missing comma/`,`). So let me know how it goes, even if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot . This code works properly now.